# Why can't I animate the 'Dimensions' property of an object?

Tags: animation

I am trying to animate/make a bar chart in Blender, but every time I try to add dimensions alongside location, rotation and scale this message pops up at the top of my screen: "Dimensions" property cannot be animated"

How do I fix this, or in any other case how can I finish my chart?

[image]

Comment: *Dimensions* property are actually a UI hack, they can't be animated directly. Actually they are no more than the *Scale* property in disguise. Animate the scale of the object instead.