# Why can't I add keyframes to dimensions

Tags: animation, keyframes, dimensions

I exported an .abc file from Marvelous Designer which doesn't show any keyframes of the animation in blender, but in the 3D view it animates.

However when I click the play button it shows the dimensions changing, indicating an animation is present, and I was wondering if there is a way to add keyframes as I am looking at exporting a USDz file with animation.

[image: no keyframes dimensions change]
[image: no keyframes dimensions change]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98093/why-cant-i-animate-the-dimensions-property-of-an-object

Answer (score 1):

*Dimensions* are just a byproduct from actual geometry size multiplied by a factor determined from objects *Scale* property.

They are a user-interface convenience to show resulting object dimensions rather than just the actual *Scale* property of the object, as such they can't be animated directly.

To have size change over time animate the scale of the object instead by keyframing *Scale X*, *Y* or *Z*.

If you still need to obtain accurate dimensions or particular sizes, adjust the intended dimension so you get the length you want on that specific axis, let Blender calculate the corresponding *Scale* factor automatically, then keyframe the resulting factor from the corresponding axis *Scale* property instead.